# How to handle (retry) failed requests with squid proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

I am using a parent proxy that has a bad connection and often fails. I am trying to retry those failed connections. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible

set
`retry_on_error on`

Referenz 
http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/retry_on_error/

Comment: I tried that but there's no in depth settings like timeout, number of retries, what kind of errors to retry, etc. When I used it I was still getting errors that were not retried.